# DE Manager after successful submission, the user remains on the page without redirection

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, url

How can I do that? After on external web site user submit the form (_successURL or _errorURL) he doesn't redirected to somewhere and remains on the page

```html
<form action="http://cl.exct.net/DEManager.aspx" name="subscribeForm" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_clientID" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="_deExternalKey" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="_action" value="add" />
    <input type="hidden" name="_returnXML" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="_successURL" value="http://example.com/Success" />
    <input type="hidden" name="_errorURL" value="http://example.com/Failed" />
</form>
```

Comment: Please update your question to include the code that's material to your question.

Comment: I do not think that my example will give anything, but I inserted it

Comment: And what about the form submission?  How have you coded that?

Comment: Also, you have values for the required `_clientID` and `_deExternalKey` inputs in your real code, right?

Comment: After clicking on the confirm button, the data from this form goes to the Data Extension and then a redirect occurs (which I do not need).
I removed _clientID and _deExternalKey on purpose, they are not needed in the example

Comment: I see the form tags and the hidden inputs, but I see no submission action. Is there a button or other action to submit it to the DE Manager? Also, as @AdamSpriggs noted, I would highly recommend steering clear of DEManager as there are some potential security risks that come from it.

Comment: are your success/error URL in the domain allow list in setup >> security >> domain allowlist?

Comment: @EazyE yes I added

Comment: @Gortonington 
yes I have `<input type="submit" value="Notify Me">`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a fan of [DEManager](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_demanager.htm&type=5).  I'd recommend creating your own simple [Code Resource CloudPage](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_cp_code_resource.htm&type=5) to consume the form data and add the row to the data extension.  You'll have a lot more control and flexibility.

There's an example of that in my [custom preference center boilerplate](https://gist.github.com/wvpv/19777e1167d6ac91e2e8) (starting on line 49).

Then you can just use a [simple AJAX form handler](https://gist.github.com/wvpv/c8d868ef4f4efa0045805576bb67387f) on your page outside of SFMC:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        table, th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

    </style>    
</head>
<body>
    <form id='form1'>
        <div><input type='text' name='name' placeholder='Name' /></div>
        <div><input type='text' name='email' placeholder='Email' /></div>
        <div><input type='text' name='number' placeholder='Mobile Number' /></div>
        <div><input type='submit' value='Submit' /></div>
    </form>
    <div id='response'></div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js "></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#form1').submit(function(){

                // show that something is loading
                $('#response').html("<b>Loading response...</b>");

                // Call ajax for pass data to other place
                $.ajax({

                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'YOURCLOUDPAGEURLHERE',
                    data: $(this).serialize() // form values

                }).done(function(data){ // executed when response is returned

                    // show the response
                    $('#response').html(data);

                }).fail(function() { // executed when post failed

                    alert( "Submission failed" );

                });

                // to prevent page refresh
                return false;

            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would have done so if the entire site in which this form is embedded had not been created outside the marketing cloud. That's why I asked this question.

Comment: Only the DE and form-handler is in SFMC, not the page.